# How do I stop two of almost every process running?

Tags: gnome, process, init

How do I stop two of almost every process running? Each duplicate process has my Username. Gnome seems to be running duplicated. I found it because an error was indicating `Failed to start server, Address already in use, (Bind Failed)`. I'm not sure what I did to cause this. Recently, to get NoMachine to display properly with my monitor disconnected, I had to run `sudo init 2`. Could it be related to that? How do I fix it?

[image: System Monitor]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to running the NoMachine server. Once I shut down NoMachine server, the duplicates disappeared.